# how do I write a paremeterized delete query using json_extract?

Tags: magento2, query, parameter

I would like to write a query like

```sql
delete from inventory_reservation where JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, '$.object_increment_id') = '<increment_id>'
```

So I created my expression in my code like

```php
$expression = "JSON_EXTRACT(metadata,'$.object_increment_id') = ?";
```

And then I try to invoke a delete action like this

```php
$this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->delete($table, [$expression, $order->getIncrementId()]);
```

However the resulting query is this one

```sql
DELETE FROM `inventory_reservation` WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(metadata,'$.object_increment_id') = ?) AND (5000447466)`
```

It's not performing a replace on the  parameterized query. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles into this, I used the following code to prepare the condition to make sure it's properly sanitized.

```php
$condition = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition("JSON_EXTRACT(metadata,'$.object_increment_id')", ['eq' => $order->getIncrementId()]);
```